# Session id being same for different client Nodejs

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express, session-cookies

Currently we are setting up session in the cookie using `express-session` with `passport.js` and `connect-redis` to store the data in redis. 
I have multiple node server serving requests. For each request without a session, I am creating a new session. Sometimes, an existing session id is being assigned to a new request. Before creating a unique session, I am checking whether the cookie is there...if it is, then I am not creating a new session. But while doing so, we are seeing that same session id being shared with different client. 
How do I know its being same? 
First user tries to login, it gives successful login and sets up the session and gives the correct information about the user profile.
Second user tries to login, it gives a successful login but sets the session as the previous i.e. first user's session , hence the second user sees the first user info in the profile section.

Code for the Session implementation:

```
function sessionImplementation() {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        if(/ucompany=s%3A/.test(req.headers['cookie'])){
            var cookie = req.headers['cookie'].split("ucompany=s%3A");
            var zCookie = cookie[1].split(".");
            var genid = zCookie[0];
            return session({
                genid:function () {
                    return genid;
                },
                store: redis,
                cookie: {
                    maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
                },
                secret: 'ucomp123',
                resave: false,
                name: "ucompany",
                saveUninitialized: true
            })(req, res, next)

        }
        return session({
            store: redis,
            cookie: {
                maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
            },
            secret: 'ucomp123',
            resave: false,
            name: "ucompany",
            saveUninitialized: true
        })(req, res, next)
    }
}
```

What is the issue and how can I fix it?

**Update 1**
As per @robertklep I have modified my code.

```
var express         = require('express');
var session         = require('express-session');
var RedisStore      = require('connect-redis')(session);
var cookieParser    = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');
var passport        = require('passport');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());// to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(compress());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//app.use(cookieParser());
var redis = new RedisStore({
  host:config.redis.url,
  port:config.redis.port, 
  prefix:'sess-'+new Date().getDate()+'-'+(new Date().getMonth()+1)+'-'+new Date().getFullYear()+':'
});
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({
    store: redis,
    cookie: {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)),
        maxAge:7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    },
    secret: 'ucomp123',
    resave: false,
    name: "ucomapny",
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: `express-session` [will handle session cookies itself](https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookie-options), so I'm not sure why you're trying to reimplement it.

Comment: What do you mean ? I am not re-implementing anything .

Comment: You are parsing the session cookies yourself, and re-instantiating the `express-session` middleware for every request.

Comment: In the readme itself, it was written ```app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}))``` This is what I am doing. I still dont understand what you mean by I am re-implementing the same. Isnt it supposed to be like this?

Comment: That's definitely _not_ what you're doing. Try using the method described in the `README` (with the correct options, of course) and see if that solves your problems.

Comment: Can you provide that as an answer ?

Comment: Only if it solves your problem ;)

Comment: Just add as answer I will run it through the app to see if it is working. Its better to have one solution rather none.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code:

- instead of letting `express-session` handle the session cookies, you're trying to handle them yourself;
- you're instantiating the session middleware for every single request, which is a waste of resources and *may* also cause problems (I haven't dug into `express-session` deep enough to make any definitive claims on that);
- `maxAge` (for the cookie) should not be a date but a number (the number of milliseconds *from now* that the cookie should remain valid); you're confusing it with `expires`, which *is* used to set a point-in-time;

The regular way of using it looks like this:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
...
app.use(session({
  store  : redis,
  cookie : { maxAge : 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
  secret : 'ucomp123',
  name   : 'ucompany',
  resave : false,
  saveUninitialized : true
});
```

Comment: I have done exactly as it is in the readme and what you have shown, but i am still getting same session id for two different client. e.g. this session id I am seeing for more than two users: MGpZbwk3qQqaDl2WdqenENIJceC6rBtq

Comment: @PranayaBehera that different client is an entirely different browser?

Comment: yes for two completely different user, with different ip as well as different machine(browser)

Comment: @PranayaBehera and you're not using a custom `genid` function? And both browsers are getting the very same cookie? There's no proxy involved, either? It's sounds fishy and I doubt it's being caused by `express-session`.

Comment: @PranayaBehera have you tried with only one Node server? In your question you're stating that you're using multiple servers.

Comment: With one server it is creating unique session id for different user/client.

Comment: @PranayaBehera how are the multiple Node servers set up? HAProxy?

Comment: multiple ec2 instance with node running on port 80. and deploying the application to each server.

Comment: @PranayaBehera but how are requests balanced between the different servers?

Comment: load balancer is front of those servers

Comment: @PranayaBehera all I can say is to take a close look at the load balancer. Session id's are generated using cryptographically strong random numbers so I don't see how duplicates can be generated.

Comment: I will look at those and try to find anything useful to debug. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

where is a genid ?

you have to generate it yourself. Use uuid package

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? Maybe you could show a code snippet with the fix in it?

Comment: app.use(session({
  genid: () => {
    return uuidv4(); // use UUIDv4s for session IDs
  },
  secret: "" + EXPRESSSESSIONSECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  name: "__session",
  cookie: myCookie,
  store: new FirestoreStore({
    dataset: ADMIN.firestore(),
    kind: "express-sessions",
  }),
}));